Trying to play a video in Flutter given MPEG video Stream data sent via a websocket
I am making a flutter app that needs to access video streams where the data is raw MPEG 1 video packets in a websocket.
I managed to get it working by sending the data through localhost UDP and then playing that UDP stream using flutter_vlc_player. BUT, this only works on android and won't work on iOS. I tried to switch to media_kit but had no luck, media kit says it supports UDP, DATA and raw mpeg video but doesn't have any documentation on how to specify that method and them. The connection string I had to use for vlc was 'udp/mpgv://@${InternetAddress.loopbackIPv4.address}:$port'. I wonder if anyone knows what connection string I would have use for media kit or a different way to do this.
(Update) I have figured out why it is not working on iOS. Sending UDP packets (at least loopback ones) on iOS is very tempermental. The RawDatagramSockect.send function will mostly return 0 indicating the sending was blocked most times when using it. The only way I could get it to send consistently was to send one udp message for every 500 incoming websocket messages. I tried using BytesBuilder to concat the 500 messages and then send them out, but, by the time we send the size of the accumulated data was too big to send out with one udp message.

I switch to using http to send the mpeg video data to flutter. I was worried about it because I didn't know how HTTP would handle the continuous sending of information but it was fine. Just make a HttpServer from dart:io. Move the first connect to a global variable, and just .add the data to it when we get the webhook. I was worried about how to send partial complete messages or separated chunks for no reason.
